# Two data points on same x coordinate overlapping

Tags: gnuplot

I started keeping a record of days that I've gone running, and the distance. I like plotting this using boxes to get an overview of how active I have been lately.

I ran into a problem today when I added yesterday's data.

As you can see from 05/04/13 there are two runs, and the plot shows two boxes on the same day (far left box). I like this behavior. 06/26/13 I had two runs again but this time the plot was only showing one (far right box). After a little playing around I realized it's because on 05/04, the larger number (in column 2) comes first, so the smaller number gets plotted on top of it. The opposite is true for 06/26, and the result is only being able to see the larger number for that day.

*Is there a way to fix this without altering my data file?*

If it's possible to do in the plot script, I wouldn't have to watch how I enter data to my file.

---

Here is the data:

```
05/04/13   1.59 
05/04/13   0.81 
05/05/13   1.56 
05/06/13   1.90 
05/08/13   2.77 
05/11/13   2.19 
05/12/13   0.93 
05/14/13   2.50 
05/15/13   1.04 
05/16/13   1.66 
06/02/13   4.02 
06/03/13   1.80 
06/04/13   1.04 
06/05/13   0.93 
06/12/13   1.18 
06/15/13   1.78 
06/16/13   1.26 
06/19/13   0.86 
06/21/13   0.93 
06/26/13   1.05 
06/26/13   1.39
```

The script:

```
set terminal x11 nopersist size 1200,645

unset mouse
unset key
unset label
unset grid

set boxwidth 86400 absolute
set style fill   solid 1.00 border lt -1
set bmargin at screen 0.08

set xdata time
set timefmt x "%m/%d/%y"
set format x "%b %d"
set xtics 86400 nomirror rotate by -90
set mxtics 0
set xrange [ "05/01/13" : "06/30/13" ] noreverse nowriteback

set ylabel "Distance" 
set ylabel textcolor lt -1 rotate by -270
set yrange [ 0.00000 : 4.50000 ] noreverse nowriteback

plot "/Users/user/Dropbox/nvalt/walks.txt" using 1:2 with boxes lt rgb "#777777"
```

An image of the plot:
[image: An image of the plot]

Comment: Easiest would be to write an `awk` script that convert your data. You can then operate the awk-script inside your plot-script, such that you don't touch the original data. It would then become `plot "<awk -f script.awk data.dat"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of files, it doesn't really matter in what order the days are, but as you mention, the ordering of the data is important. I was able to obtain the required output, by simply replacing

```
plot "/Users/user/Dropbox/nvalt/walks.txt" using 1:2 with boxes lt rgb "#777777"
```

By

```
plot "<sort -r /Users/user/Dropbox/nvalt/walks.txt" using 1:2 with boxes lt rgb "#777777"
```

This should also work for more than two data points for the same date.

Comment: Thanks, this works exactly like I had hoped! A question though: I assume the sort command is just a UNIX command, I glanced at the man page for sort and saw that -r is just "reverse the result of comparisons". I'm curious why it reverses the problem data set but not the first entry that is working like I want?

Comment: @mindheavy Because it sort first. So first by date, then by the second column (but low to high). But, you want them high to low, therefor `-r`. Suppose you'd only wanted to show the top bar, then you could use just `sort` without flags.